# REACT: You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the whole error message im receiving when im doing click on a div (the one with className="hotel-row")

> index.js:1 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a
> string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
> components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
> component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up
> default and named imports.
>
> Check your code at HotelList.js:27.

This component is connnected to redux

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => state;

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    loadHotels: async () => {
      dispatch(loadHotels());
    },
  };
}

function HotelList(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.loadHotels();
  }, []);

  if (props.hotels.length != undefined) {
    const data = props.hotels;
    const listItems = data.map((d) => (
      <div className="hotel-row" onClick={() => <Redirect to={"/hotel/"+d.name} />}>
        <Hotel name={d.name} category={d.category} image={d.image} description={d.description} />
      </div>
    ));

    return <div className="hotel-list">{listItems}</div>;
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Loading...</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HotelList);
```

This is how my router looks

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Route, Switch, withRouter, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import HotelList from "../Components/HotelList";
import HotelPage from "../Components/HotelPage"
const Router = () => {
    const renderFor404Routes = () => <Redirect to="/" />;
    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exactly component={HotelList} exact path="/" />
          <Route exact path="/hotel/:name" component={HotelPage}  />
          <Route path="/" exactly component={renderFor404Routes} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  };
  
  export default withRouter(Router);
```

And this is where it is supposed to redirect

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
const HotelPage = () => {

  let { name } = useParams();


  useEffect(() => {
       
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {name}
    </div>
  );
};

export default HotelPage
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it this way

```
<div className="hotel-row" onClick={() => props.history.push("/hotel/"+d.name)}>
        <Hotel name={d.name} category={d.category} image={d.image} description={d.description} />
      </div>
```